# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error. Salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

**[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.**

We trying to update the record data dynamically.
we are sending the data from child to parent. We are trying to update the JSON object based on dynamically key value but getting an error.

```
@track tasks = []; // it contains task records
handleChange(event) {
   let response = event.detail;
   let rec = this.tasks[response.index];    
   // checked null values
   rec[response.realApiName] = response.value; // Error on this Line  if we comment this part then it works
}
```

In LWC, is js support dynamic Data Binding ?

Comment: Can you post both the markup and the js controller?

Comment: I have implemented the same in the playground. And it's working. May be an issue in the rendring part of a child component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fLKi5dyR/35/edit

Comment: To help with the debugging, make sure your dev org has the session cache off otherwise what you see in the UI is not what is actually in the codebase and turn off CDN for good measure in dev orgs/sandboxes.